# how to remove extra dots from a float numbers using php

Tags: php

How can i remove extra dots from a float value.

Example:

I have a **`$amount= 61786.6605..`** in my php page.How can i get output like `$amount=61786.6605` .
Please help me  to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floatval() might help you :)

`echo floatval($amount);`

---

```
$amount = '61786.6605..';
echo $amount . "<br />";
$print = floatval($amount);
echo $print;
```

So the printed result from both variables - the one with extra dots and floated are:

> 61786.6605..
>
> 61786.6605